# Proguard crashes on Scala code depending on Multiverse STM

Tags: java, scala, crash, proguard, stm

I'm trying to optimize some Scala code which relies on the Multiverse STM (0.6.2) with Proguard. I'm using the STM in conjunction with akka. As I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error while inlining subroutines:
    Class       = [org/multiverse/transactional/refs/BasicRef]
    Method      = [<init>()V]
    Exception   = [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException] (-1)
```

I'm optimizing with the following flags:

```
-forceprocessing

-libraryjars ${java.home}/lib/rt.jar
-injars      ${jar.name}
-outjars     ${jar.opt.name}

-dontobfuscate

-dontnote
-dontwarn
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Do you know of a workaround for this problem (besides the obvious -dontoptimize)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After losing even more hours on proguard trying to fix this same problem, I switched to one-jar ( https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar ) and poof it worked first time. I suggest that unless there is something specific that you need from proguard ( shrinkage, bytecode obfuscation ) just use one-jar.

Anytime I have to configure proguard I find myself in a battle. Often when configuring sbt I also find myself in a battle. Put them together and it's a recipe for trouble.

Good luck.
-Andy